# What do I have to import or install to use mshook function in my project?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, hook, cydia-substrate

I have downloaded a .mm file from the internet.  It includes a `MSHookFunction` call.  When I compile the project it says:

> use of undeclared identifier MSHookFunction

Answer (score 0):

You have to obtain substrate.h and libsubstrate.a to build.
You have to use jailbroken iPhone with MobileSubstrate to execute it. It does not run on simulator.

Comment: Where do i get those files?